# Live update jquery Jslider

Tags: jquery, jslider

In my website I am using a Jquery Jslider portion for show/hide products according to the selected price range. I am also using Jquery `scroll()` for load more product when scrolldown the page. I need to update the JSlider price when new products are loaded from scroll. How can I make it happen? I searched a lot. But didn't get the answer.

My code is

```
<div class="layout-slider">
    <input id="Slider2" type="slider" name="price" value="5000;150000" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery("#Slider2").slider({ from: 5000, to: 150000, step: 1, dimension: '&nbsp;$' });
</script>

<input type="text" value="" id="sl-change" /><input type="button" value="Change" id="change" />
```

This is a sample code where I try to input value in a text field and update the slider according to that. If I do this, I will get solution for my problem. Please help me

My fiddle test link is given below

Jsfiddle link : [Link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/p47kZ/)

Comment: Plz add a jsFiddle or jsBin link for it

Comment: @SSS, JSfiddle link:  [This is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/p47kZ/) Please try to help me. Thank you

Comment: @SSS, I edited the above link. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#Slider2").slider( "option", "from", 100 );
$("#Slider2").slider( "option", "to", 1020 );
```

in you case:

```
$("#sl-change").on("change",function(){

    $("#Slider2").slider( "option", "from", $(this).val() );

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. But it didn't work for me. It didn't give any response to the slider :(

Comment: It too didn't work for me. Can you please check my code on [This Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/p47kZ/)

Comment: Oh i see - you use http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/ to generate the silder.

This plugin have no function to reset the limits.
Use Jquery-UI Slider (http://jqueryui.com/slider/) - than you can use the solution i posted.

Comment: Yeah exactly that is the problem.. No options.. :(

Comment: I already saw the link u given. But my theme has inbuilt jslider.. :(